# Devolver el total de montos por mes en un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Debo crear un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecute automáticamente al momento que yo haga registros de una tabla, esta tabla contiene las siguientes columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El propósito es que por cada nombre mes y monto que voy ingresando en la tabla, me sume el monto al mes que escriba. Evidentemente imagino yo que al finalizar debería aparecerme doce columnas con el nombre de cada mes en ellas mostrando el monto total de cada una de ellas.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GRAFICOLINEAL(@MES VARCHAR, @VALOR FLOAT)
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT MES, MONTODEBITOFLOAT FROM PRUEBAOPEX
END
```

De momento tengo así mi estructura. No tengo claro cuantas variables debería crear, si una por mes. O si debo utilizar más parámetros.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: no deberías pensar en hacer un stored procedure sino en un trigger o disparador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución pasa por una consulta que sume el monto y agrupe ese valor por el mes. El procedimiento no requiere de parámetros::

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GRAFICOLINEAL
AS
BEGIN 
   SELECT MES, SUM(MONTODEBITOFLOAT) AS MONTO
   FROM PRUEBAOPEX
   GROUP BY MES
END
```